# Azure pipelines can't run commands on Windows - SSH

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, azure-pipelines, devops

`enter code here`We connected our Azure DevOps Pipeline with a Windows web server.
This pipeline should be connecting, dropping some files (including powershell)
and run the powershell script.

Dropping files into the server is being done with the task *WindowsMachineFileCopy@2* which works perfectly fine.

When then, we try to run commands into the server though, it looks that the commands run but it does nothing.

**Azure task:**

```
            - task: SSH@0
        displayName: 'Setting up APP1'
        inputs:
          sshEndpoint: 'SSH - GTP325 - APP1'
          runOptions: 'commands'
          commands: |
            echo 'Changing permissions to APP1.zip file...'
            icacls .\APP1\ /reset /t /c /q 

            echo "Current directory"
            dir

            echo "Changing Directory.."
            cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\APP1

            echo "Display current directory"
            dir

            
            echo 'Decompressing APP1.zip files...'
            tar -xf .\APP1\APP1.zip
            echo 'running scripts for setup...'
            .\APP1\APP1\APP1-file-check.ps1
          readyTimeout: '20000'
```

**Pipeline logs**

```
Trying to establish an SSH connection to ***@10.*.*.*:22
Successfully connected.
echo 'Changing permissions to APP1.zip file...'
'Changing permissions to APP1.zip file...'

icacls .\APP1\ /reset /t /c /q 
Successfully processed 24 files; Failed processing 0 files

echo "Current directory"
"Current directory"

dir

Volume in drive C has no label.

 Volume Serial Number is F69E-D5FC


 Directory of C:\Users\Administrator

echo "Changing Directory.."
"Changing Directory.."

cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\APP1
echo "Display current directory"
"Display current directory"

dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.

 Volume Serial Number is F69E-D5FC


 Directory of C:\Users\Administrator

echo 'Decompressing APP1.zip files...'
'Decompressing APP1.zip files...'

tar -xf .\APP1\APP1.zip
##[error]t
##[error]ar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '.\APP1\APP1.
##[error]zip'

##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine.
Finishing: Setting up APP1
```

Note:
Build agent is Windows.
Tried: SSH@0 Inline - doesn't work on Windows
SSH@ Script file with powershell, Shell, bash - don't work either

I will appreciate every hint on this

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tar -xf .\Desktop\APP1\APP1.zip`?

Comment: Hi Mathias, you re right on this. I changed directory before I run the tar command but I didnt have the task, updated.
In any case this doesnt work, not because cant find the file but it doesnt accept the command.
Also, any command seem to be "run" but eventually skipped as you can see from the logs